# java.lang.ClassCastException only on Android 2.3?

Tags: java, android, button

When i run my app on `Android 2.3` devices.I am getting an `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView` .But it works perfect in other Devices.

If i Comment the below Lines it is working.But i can't find any Error's in these Lines.
Any Suggestions ???

```
            up = (Button) findViewById(R.id.up);
            down = (Button) findViewById(R.id.down);
            start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
            stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
            up.setOnClickListener(this);
            down.setOnClickListener(this);
            start.setOnClickListener(this);
            stop.setOnClickListener(this);
```

**Activity**

```
public class Presentation extends MainActivity implements ControllerDroidActionReceiver, OnClickListener
{
    Button up, down, start, stop;
    private ControllerDroid application;
    private ControlView controlView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.application = (ControllerDroid) this.getApplication();

        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setTitle("Presentation");

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.presentation, null, false);
        mDrawer.addView(contentView, 0);

        up = (Button) findViewById(R.id.up);
        down = (Button) findViewById(R.id.down);
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        up.setOnClickListener(this);
        down.setOnClickListener(this);
        start.setOnClickListener(this);
        stop.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if (v == up)
        {
             application.sendAction(new KeyboardAction(19));
            // Log.i("Button", "UP");
        }
        else if (v == down)
        {
             application.sendAction(new KeyboardAction(20));
        }
        else if (v == start)
        {
             application.sendAction(new KeyboardAction(26));
            // Log.i("Button", "STARTED PPT");
        }
        else if (v == stop)
        {
             application.sendAction(new KeyboardAction(23));
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        this.application.registerActionReceiver(this);
    }

    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        this.application.unregisterActionReceiver(this);
    }   
    public void receiveAction(ControllerDroidAction action)
    {
        if (action instanceof ScreenCaptureResponseAction)
        {
            this.controlView.receiveAction((ScreenCaptureResponseAction) action);
        }
    }

}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/up"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="UP" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/down"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="DOWN" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="start" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stop"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Stop" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What does your view XML look like?

Comment: It's clearly one of the four `findViewById` calls - find out which one by commenting one at a time.  Then check your XML to make sure you're using the correct IDs.

Comment: is really that **HARD** to find out why you have ClassCastException?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//put `setContentview(R.layout.presentation)`

or do it as below

```
up = (Button)contentView. findViewById(R.id.up);
        down = (Button)contentView. findViewById(R.id.down);
        start = (Button)contentView. findViewById(R.id.start);
        stop = (Button)contentView. findViewById(R.id.stop);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with **contentView.findViewById()** because you are not doing setContentView().

```
    up = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.up);
    down = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.down);
    start = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.start);
    stop = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.stop);
```

May be some where you used at least one of them id for ImageView.
It may help you..